# Pursuing a new graduate degree after academic expulsion

Tags: graduate-admissions, application-cover-letter, expulsion

I was in a master’s program. I completed one year completed, but got expelled due to my GPA dropping below what was needed.  I was put on probation and was given one semester to pull up my average by getting an A in all three classes I was taking, but I only got an A in two of them.

I have the option to apply for re-admittance and will do so, but just in case I want to apply to other programs, perhaps as a transfer. If needed, I’d apply fresh and start over.

In my new applications, should I explain my situation (life changes, job loss), or would it be better to not dwell too much on it?

Comment: Generally if you are willing to pay for your degree it is exceedingly possible to find a school willing to accept your money.

Comment: Vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". Please respond to @Nat's comment. You completed one year. What was your GPA of your first semester?

Comment: @Nat - I think I understood what OP was asking and have edited the question to make it clearer.  Also, I tried to focus the question.